# How to query for all entries a WHERE "b MEMBER OF a.list"

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpql, memberof

I have an entity, let's say A, which has a field that is a list of another entity, let's say B.

This is A:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "a")
public class A implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sequenceGenerator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "sequenceGenerator")
    private Long id;

    @ManyToMany
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
    @JoinTable(name = "a_b",
               joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="as_id", referencedColumnName="id"),
               inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="bs_id", referencedColumnName="id"))
    private Set<B> bs = new HashSet<>();
}
```

This is B:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "b")
public class B implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sequenceGenerator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "sequenceGenerator")
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;
}
```

Now, what I'm trying to achieve is to be able to query for all the entries a of A, having an entity b of B in a.bs

Tha actual query is show below:

```
@Repository
public interface ARepository extends JpaRepository<A, Long> {
    @Query("SELECT DISTINCT a FROM A a LEFT JOIN FETCH a.bs bs WHERE :b MEMBER OF bs")
    List<A> findAllByB(@Param("b") B b);
}
```

Wasn't it supposed to work like this?

However the error I get is the one below, I put it on pastebin due to exceeding the size limits of the post:

[Log](https://pastebin.com/yH74ijn7)

Comment: What's your problem?

Comment: @MạnhQuyếtNguyễn I added the log to the post

Comment: Are you posting your real query with just alias A and B for your entity?

Comment: yes, of course.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need `join` here.

Try this query:

```
@Query("SELECT DISTINCT a FROM A a WHERE :b MEMBER OF a.bs")
```

You're using `MEMBER OF` operator but match it with another table, not the collection itself so it leads to sql syntax error.

By default `PostgreSQL` create a `public` schema, if you don't specify schema for you entity, it will be not found when hibernate checking against public schema.

```
@Table(name = "b", schema = "schemaname")
```

Comment: join is needed otherwise the list field would be void

Comment: Did you try my query?

Comment: it doesn't compile

Comment: Sorry, change it to `MEMBER OF a.bs`

Comment: same stuff as the log

Comment: I'm doubting that JPA only allows to use primitive types or wrapper classes as query params.

Comment: You have problem with your `JoinTable`

Comment: I think I found your problem, you're using postgreSQL but do not specify a `schema` for it. Try to add your `schema` to your entity

Comment: it is already configured in my application.yml, but I'll check your suggestion and let you know